# Unknown Character in Netbeans and Console

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode

I have a text file "abc.txt" encoded in utf-8 data being a set of emoticons from [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon):
`(^_^) happy`

My code extracts this info from the file to the netbeans stdout
My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("abc.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

In netbeans the output is this :

[image]

While in console the output is:
[image]

What is this character?
And how do I remove this?

Comment: Delete all content from your file and write it your self just to check what went wrong in your case.

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi : I manually typed `happy` in notepad, saved as 'abc.txt' in UTF-8 encoding and tried the program. Gives the same non-printable character in the beginning. (BOM apparently)

Comment: Changing the encoding from UTF-8 to unicode seems to solve the problem. [BOM WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: "If you save a file as UTF-8, Notepad will put the BOM (byte order mark) EF BB BF at the beginning of the file." [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769311/how-windows-notepad-interpret-characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console output looks like a UTF-8 encoded [Byte Order Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) (BOM, U+FEFF), bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF, misinterpreted according to some legacy 8-bit character encoding.

Either save the file without BOM, or make your program recognize and skip the BOM at the start of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non printable character at the beginning of the file added by a widows editor. It is necessary to remove it in the file or skip it by Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I manually typed `happy` in notepad, saved as 'abc.txt' in UTF-8 encoding and tried the program. Gives the same non-printable character in the beginning. Is it standard for UTF-8 documents to do so?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used windows for ages:), Windows editors added a special two bytes at the begging of the file to indicate that it is UTF8 document :), simply remove them. I can not recommend windows tool to do it. Try editor in Netbeens.